# How to show an ArrayList during debugging of VBScript code?

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript

I have an ArrayList in VBScript:

```
Dim oList
Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
oList.Add "a"
oList.Add "b"
```

When debugging this code in Visual Studio it shows the list as

```
[+] oList    | {...}
```

however clicking the `[+]` does not expand the list. I suppose this is because of VBScripts late binding(?).

Is there a trick to expand the list? Is it possible to "cast" it to an ArrayList and then expand it or some other magic thing to examine the list except manually adding the lines

```
    oList(0) | "a"
    oList(1) | "b"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `ArrayList` to an Array of Variants by using its [.ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fcyyh2hb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

`oList.ToArray()` in the Watch tab should work (may depend on debugger/version); adding an extra variable set to `oList.ToArray()` could be a fallback.